# How to solve "invalid value for property 'FontSize': 'Large' " warning in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created new custom control in Xamarin.Forms which is derived from View and used FontSize property customize the custom control text. I will provide Large, Small Medium type in FontSize. So, FontSizeConverter attribute added above the FontSize property. in my custom control.

**[C#]:**

```
 public class CustomControl : View, IParentThemeElement
    {

        [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
        public double FontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
        }


       public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
           "FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(CustomControl), GetDefaultTextFontSize(), BindingMode.Default, null, OnFontSizePropertyChanged);

}
```

Then FontSize given in string as you see in the below sample code in my custom control and it is working fine. But i am getting warning message in Xml code like "invalid value for property 'FontSize': 'Large'.

**[XAML]:**

```
<edit:CustomControl HeightRequest="100" FontSize="Large"  x:Name="editor">
```

I referred Xamarin.Forms Entry FontSize. They used the same code. But in Entry, I not found any warnings. Anyone please help to resolve the warning.

Thanks,

Comment: `FontSize` should been assigned a double value ,not a string .

Comment: Check Xamarin.Forms Entry. FontSize type is double. But we can give in string like Large, Small, Medium

Comment: Post the code in your custom control .

Comment: updated code snippet

Comment: Well I think the issue is because your declaring type is a different class whereas where you are declaring it is a different class, `public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
           "FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(CustomControl), GetDefaultTextFontSize(), BindingMode.Default, null, OnFontSizePropertyChanged);`

Comment: Sorry. I missed to change the code snippet. In my source, everything all right. Class is same

Comment: It seems a issue of IDE ,you can directly debug your app.It works fine on my side.